# Попытка шифрования путем сдвига n-ого кол-ва битов ( с++ )

Tags: c++, xcode, byte, bit

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
unsigned char rrotate(unsigned char val, int n);
unsigned char lrotate(unsigned char val, int n);
void show_binary(unsigned int u);
int main()
{
     int q=0;
    cout<<"Введите количество сдвигов(бит, это и будет ключем): ";
    cin>>q;
 char ch = 'T';
cout << "Исходное значение в двоичном коде:\n";
show_binary(ch);
cout << "Шифрование путем сдвига битов влево:\n";
for(int i=0; i < 8; i++) {
ch = rrotate(ch, q);
show_binary(ch);
}
cout << "Разшифровка путем сдвига битов вправо:\n";
for(int i=0; i < 8; i++) {
ch=lrotate(ch, q);
show_binary(ch);
}
return 0;
}
unsigned char lrotate(unsigned char val, int n)
{
unsigned int t;
t=val;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
t = t << 1;
if(t & 256)
t = t | 1;
}
return t;
}
unsigned char rrotate(unsigned char val, int n) {
unsigned int t;
t=val;
t = t<<8;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
t=t>>1;
if(t & 128)
t = t | 32768;
}
    t= t>>8;
    return t;
}

    void show_binary(unsigned int u) {
int t;
for (t=128; t>0;t=t/2)
 if(u & t) cout<<"1";
     else cout<<"0";
cout<<"\n";
}
```

Программа выполняет шифрование символа в двоичном коде q-е кол-во раз. Можно ли сделать само шифрование с помощью строки, например. Не могу понять реально ли это, и как это можно реализовать. ( Скорее всего я не очень понятно выразился что я хочу сделать, заранее прошу прощение ) Подскажите, пожалуйста, путь истинный на решение этой задачи ( если можно с объяснением )
P.S. это не какое-то задание, я просто решил это сделать, и не прошу делать это за меня!

Comment: @White, не слушайте "умников" (обычно они сами не в состоянии ничего придумать). Посмотрите, вот так вращать `char` значительно быстрее `unsigned char
rot_l (char c, int n)
{
  n &= 7;
  unsigned v = (unsigned char)c;
  v <<= n;
  
  return v | (v >> 8);
}

unsigned char
rot_r (char c, int n)
{
  return rot_l(c, 8 - n);
}` / Что еще у вас не получается, уточните, из вопроса не очень понятно, что вы имеете в виду под *`"Можно ли сделать само шифрование с помощью строки"`*

Comment: @avp я хотел попробовать заменить ключ(q, который задается цифрой) на ключ строкой, что-бы ключ к шифру был в виде строки, реально ли такое сделать?

Comment: @avp а Вы не могли бы пояснить почему вот этот вариант быстрее? Мне не очень понятен этот код, который Вы оставили

Comment: @White, вы же видите, что в этом варианте совсем нет циклов. Т.е. нет условных переходов, которые в основном замедляют программу. Возможно не понятно еще это -- `n &= 7`. Тут мы безусловно обрезаем значение величины сдвига до 7 (поскольку в байте всего 8 бит), чтобы не проверять его правильность

Comment: *`"я хотел попробовать заменить ключ(q, который задается цифрой) на ключ строкой, что-бы ключ к шифру был в виде строки, реально ли такое сделать?"`* -- да, конечно реально. Например, код каждого символа строки может задавать величину битового вращения очередного символа текста. Когда в процессе шифрования строка закончится, надо просто начать ее с начала (и так, по кругу, пока не закончится шифруемый текст)